# cap/floor valuation in a hypothetical scenario using monte carlo simulation

Tags: monte-carlo, cap

How can I do a cap/floor valuation in a hypothetical scenario using monte carlo simulations of some interest rate model?

My conditions:

- (For example) I want to do valuation of a cap option under a hypothetical scenario where a 200 bps parallel upwards shift to current yield curve and a %25 increase in volatility occur.
- I want to use monte carlo simulations to generate yield curve paths according to some interest rate model and then calculate the value of projected cashflows.
- The crucial assumption is that the hypothetical shock is instantaneous. I think this implies that first I want to shock the parameters and then do the valuation in this new rate/volatility environment, not the other way around (first simulate paths and then apply the yield curve shift).

Follow-up questions (if these conditions above make sense and it is possible to implement a solution):

- Can I use an arbitrage free model to simulate these paths? Because I assume you can not calibrate model parameters (e.g. drift and volatility) to this new shocked scenario given that current market prices (yield curve shape and swaption prices for example in a HW model) are relevant for base scenario only?
- Can you tell which interest rate models are suitable for such a task?
- Do you know any papers or books about this specific subject (stress testing option valuations)?